# Writing an entire array to QFile

Tags: qt, qfile

The [`QFile::write()` documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#write) says:

> Writes at most `maxSize` bytes of data from data to the device. Returns the number of bytes that were actually written, or -1 if an error occurred.

(Yes that's the entire documentation - unusually poor for Qt.)

This seems to imply that it is common for it not to write all of the data you pass. Does that mean I should call `write()` in a loop, passing in the remaining unwritten data until it has fully written it?

If so that seems like a pain. Is there some convenience function in Qt that will do it for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This seems to imply that it is **common** for it not to write all of the data you pass

Common, no, but it is possible, which we'll see, below.

> Is there some convenience function in Qt that will do it for me?

If you're writing a whole file, a better method would be to use [QSaveFile](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsavefile.html), for "safely writing to files".

As it states in the documentation for `QSaveFile`:

> QSaveFile automatically detects errors while writing, such as the full partition situation, where write() cannot write all the bytes.

So a full partition would be one instance that could cause a `QIODevice::write`  to fail to fully write data to disk. Disk failure, removal of a portable storage device or network drive during a write to those can also cause only partial data to be written.

Comment: Aha ok `QSaveFile` is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @Timmmm, glad to be of service. It would be useful if the documentation for `QFile` actually mentioned `QSaveFile`; I'm sure many users of Qt are unaware of its existence.

Comment: Ha I was just looking to solve this same problem again and had of course forgotten about `QSaveFile`; found myself back here. The docs still don't mention it. :-/

Answer (score 0):

> Yes that's the entire documentation - unusually poor for Qt.

There's not much more to it.

> Does that mean I should call `write()` in a loop

Something has to prevent `write` from finishing, perhaps the missing bit is that it won't fail to write `maxBytes` for no reason. I.e. it's not done to spite you, but because `write` can't proceed.

If you remove the condition that caused it to fail you can call it again. In most cases, there's no point in retrying - when `write` fails to write what you meant to write, you're done and you handle it as an error.